# Compiler Elides Assignment of Constant Without Setting Variable

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VC++ 2010 Express. I've written the following routine:

```
HRESULT DLTimeStampNow::Receive(IMediaSample *pSample)
{
    long long fnum, fnum2;
    REFERENCE_TIME timeStart=0, timeEnd=10000;

    // make this sample available for the next worker-thread call to Transform()

    pSample->AddRef();

    CRefTime rtStream;

    timeStart = 0;
    timeEnd = 10000;

    pSample->SetTime(&timeStart, &timeEnd);

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    if (pSampleWaiting != NULL)
        ((IMediaSample*)pSampleWaiting)->Release();

    pSampleWaiting = pSample;

    SetEvent(hSampleIsReady);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

    return S_OK;
}
```

This is part of a work in progress, which is why variables like fnum and rtStream are present but unused.

At run-time, the VC++ debugger refuses to put breakpoints at `timeStart = 0` or `timeEnd = 10000`, which would be fine except it also *fails to initialize them*. The debugger shows they contain garbage at the point when execution reaches `pSample->SetTime(&timeStart, &timeEnd);`. To cope with this, I have added `=0` and `=10000` to the variable declarations. This works, but why is it necessary? I am guessing the compiler is doing some kind of optimization where it avoids the constant assignments in the code, but it is also forgetting(?) to ever actually assign values to `timeStart` and `timeEnd` (unless I initialize them in their declaration statement, as above).

What gives?

Comment: Can you narrow down this problem to a simple example that other people can compile (without having all the rest of your code present)?

Comment: You have optimization turned off, right?

Comment: @Greg I'm working on that right now.

Comment: @jdigital No, some optimizations are turned on and I am betting that's relevant. But, it shouldn't be. That routine is hardly the sort of thing that I would expect to defeat modern opmtimization methods.

Comment: More likely it's fooling the debugger rather than defeating modern optimization methods.  Step into SetTime (running without your extra initializations) and see if the values are correct.

Comment: @jdigital You just might have it! I can't step _into_ SetTime (Microsoft wrote that one and I don't have the source), but _after_ it returns, the debugger displays the correct values for  `timeStart` and `timeEnd`. Any idea how that happens? (And, thanks!)

Comment: @jdigital Actually, in the Debug build, I _do_ have optimizations turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler optimization could do various things to cause this behavior, such as storing local variables in registers or turning single-use variables into constants.  If you want to understand what's happening, one approach is to use assembly view/mode in the debugger to see what happens before and after the function call to `SetTime`.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer because jdigital figured out that it was the debugger, not the optimizer, that was misleading me. Well done, friend!